# ¿Cuál es la etimología de la palabra "tertulia"?

Tags: etimología, historia

El término "tertulia" se usa para denominar a cualquier reunión entre amigos con el propósito de conversar y pasar un buen rato. El [diccionario de la Real Academia Española](https://dle.rae.es/tertulia) da a 'tertulia' un origen incierto, incluso [Wikipedia](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tertulia) no da mucha información, más allá de un posible origen romano. ¿Tiene alguien más información sobre el origen y la etimología de este término? ¿Alguien ha investigado más sobre esta palabra, o siquiera una hipótesis sobre su origen?

Comment: http://etimologias.dechile.net/?tertulia

Answer (score 1):

El diccionario etimológico de Corominas dice: "Es verosímil que se diera el nombre de *tertulianos*, med. S. XVII, a los espectadores más cultos, por las alusiones que se hacían a Tertuliano en los sermones y cenáculos del S. XVII, y que de ahí se extrajera tertulia como nombre de la parte del teatro donde se sentaban estos espectadores, o como nombre de los cenáculos más o menos eruditos."